# Displaying JSON data in EJS template - Unexpected string syntax error

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, ejs

I am trying to display the results of a MySQL query using EJS. The query returns a JSON array in the following form:

```
[ TextRow {
    'Sample ID': 'S0001',
    'Panel ID': 'P0001',
     Gene: BRAC1,
    'DNA z-score': 0.7
     Chromosome: 11 },
  TextRow {
      'Sample ID': 'S0003',
      'Panel ID': 'P0009',
       Gene: PTEN,
      'DNA z-score': 0.5,
       Chromosome: 5 } ]
```

I have the following EJS code:

```
<% if(data.length) { %>
   <% for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
      <tr>
         <td><%=data[i].'Sample ID'%></td>
         <td><%=data[i].'Variant ID'%></td>
         <td><%=data[i].Gene%></td>
         <td><%=data[i].'DNA z-score'%></td>
         <td><%=data[i].Chromosome%></td>
      </tr>
   <% } %>
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected string in "/Users/userone/Documents/Project/results.ejs"
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error and how to resolve it. For the keys 'Sample ID', 'Panel ID' and 'DNA z-score', these are in single quotes, so I'm not sure what the right syntax is to use. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: its not valid JSON. In JSON, you have double quotes around keys and string values

Comment: What is the format of the objects in the array then?

Comment: take a look at [working with JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)